# How do I change the default WordPress e-mail ID for sent e-mail?

Tags: plugins

I have created a blog website at `careerdemo.com` and installed WordPress to run it.

When a person signs up, they get an email from the address `wordpress@careerdemo.com` (this is, I guess, a default setting in WordPress).

I want to change that, so that e-mails come from my own address,`contact@careerdemo.com`. (So any new user will get e-mails from my own e-mail address, `contact@careerdemo.com`.) How do I customize my FROM e-mail address?

Comment: Do you want to customise the e-mail *address* or the e-mail *ID* (whatever that means)? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @TRiG question updated very much clear now thanks :)

Comment: did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your functions.php:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');

function new_mail_from($old) {
 return 'your email address';
}
function new_mail_from_name($old) {
 return 'your name or your website';
}
```

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: i have created a technical blog+website if you are interested please mail me ashuthinks[at]gmail.com